# About using evaluate in a method or in my main .js

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a method to generalize some operation i use often but it doesn't seem to work and i'm not figuring out why.
I'm using the same code (except for trying to make it a little more generic) in my main js and in a method i declare in a support js but in my main it works and in the support js doesn't.

Here's the main js (i'm reporting only the code i'm trying to insert in a method and the call to the method i've done and the general structure of the main js)

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const Console = require('../core/console');
const login = require('../core/login/login');
const Utility = require('../core/utility');
const utility = new Utility();
const localConfig = {
    target: 'https://xyz.it/',
    userName: 'xyz',
    password: 'xyz',
    windowWidth: 1920,
    windowHeight: 1080,
    headless: false
};

async function runTest() {
    // ...some code here

        const numPagineObj = await page.evaluate(
            () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ui-grid-pager-max-pages-number'),
                e => e.innerHTML)
        );
        let numPagine = (Utility.convertHtmlToString(numPagineObj[0])).replace('/ ','');

        let zzzz = await utility.getTextFromSelectorArray(page, '.ui-grid-pager-max-pages-number', 0, 'innerHTML');

        // ...some other code here
}

runTest();
```

and following there's the method i've declared in another js

```
 getTextFromSelectorArray = async (page, selector, indexElem, attributeName) => {
    try {
        await page.waitForSelector(selector);
        let elems = [];
        console.error(Console.FgRed, 'selector ' + selector);
        console.error(Console.FgRed, 'attributeName ' + attributeName);
        switch(attributeName){
            case 'outerHTML':
                elems = await page.evaluate( (selector) => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.outerHTML); } );
                break;
            case 'innerHTML':
                elems = await page.evaluate( (selector) => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.innerHTML); } );
                break;
            case 'textContent':
                elems = await page.evaluate( (selector) => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.textContent); } );
                break;
        }

        console.error(Console.FgRed, 'elems ' + elems);
        return ((elems !== undefined && elems.length > 0) ? Utility.convertHtmlToString(elems[indexElem]) : 'xxx- NotFound -xxx');
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(Console.FgRed, e.message);
    }
};
```

In my main i've tried to print the variables numPagine and zzzz and i got the following on my console

numPagine: '4' and
zzzz: 'xxx- NotFound -xxx' (note: that's a default value i've used in my method if the array i'm trying to create is undefined or empty)

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks to all!

---

EDIT:
After a suggestion of Code-Apprentice i've tried to make the method exactly the same as it is in the main and it worked. The thing that made it work was using directly the selector instead of passing it trought a variable.

what my method is like now that worked:

```js
    getTextFromSelectorArray = async (page, selector, indexElem, attributeName) => {
            try {
                const numPagineObj = await page.evaluate(
                    () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ui-grid-pager-max-pages-number'),
                        e => e.innerHTML)
                );
                let numPagine = Utility.convertHtmlToString(numPagineObj[indexElem]);
                return numPagine;
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(Console.FgRed, e.message);
            }
        };
```

The problem is now how can i make it work passing the selector in a variable?

---

EDIT 2: I've got what i was missing!
Writing the code like this 'elems = await page.evaluate( (s) => { return Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(s),el => el.outerHTML); }, selector );' instead of 'elems = await page.evaluate( (selector) => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.outerHTML); } );' makes work my code.

Comment: On a side note, the support js i'm using is called utility.js and i insert it with the first istructions of my main js --> const utility = new Utility(); (row 5 of the main js)

Comment: "I'm using the same code (except for trying to make it a little more generic)" I would back up a step and make the method **exactly** the same as it was in `main.js` originally. Make sure you can get that to work before you try to generalize it. When you start generalizing the function and it doesn't work, use `console.log()` or your favorite debugger to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Also, feel free to [edit] your question if you need to add more details rather than posting a comment.

Comment: Ok, (i feel stupid right now...): i've tried to make the method exactly the same as it is in the main and it worked. The thing that made it work was using directly the selector instead of passing it trought a variable. The problem is now how can i make it work passing the selector in a variable?

Comment: One difference I see is that you have `page.evaluate(() => {})` in the version that works, but `page.evaluate((selector) => {})` in the version that doesn't. I think you need to pass the selector to `evaluate()`: `page.evaluate((selector) => {}, selector)`. One thing to keep track of is the different variables named `selector`.

Comment: Alternatively, don't declare another variable named `selector`: `page.evaluate(() => {/* Just use the outer "selector" here */ })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elems = await page.evaluate( (selector) => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.outerHTML); } );
```

The problem (I think) is that you declare the callback to accept a parameter named `selector`, but you do not pass any values to `evaluate()` to pass in for this parameter. Instead, you should just use the `selector` variable that is accepted by `SelectorArray`. In other words, don't declare `selector` as a new variable:

```
elems = await page.evaluate( () => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.outerHTML); } );
```

Comment: Leaving untouched the other code and writing 'elems = await page.evaluate( () => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.outerHTML); } );' gives this message in the terminal console --> Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: selector is not defined at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:48.
Instead, using 'elems = await page.evaluate( (selector) => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.outerHTML, selector); } );' doesn't give any error message but doesn't give any result either

Comment: Obviously neither writing 'elems = await page.evaluate( () => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.outerHTML, selector); } );' gives any result but the error message Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: selector is not defined at puppeteer_evaluation_script:1:48

Comment: I've found and written the solution to my problem on the second edit i made on the main body of this question. @Code-Apprentice thanks for your help!

Comment: @PasqualeSqualo Please post an actual answer rather than editing your question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've got what i was missing! Writing the code like this

```
elems = await page.evaluate( (s) => { return Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(s),el => el.outerHTML); }, selector );
```

instead of

```
elems = await page.evaluate( (selector) => { Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(selector),el => el.outerHTML); } );
```

makes work my code.